# react setvalue first time onClick not working

Tags: reactjs

Trying to control an input type number in React.

It seems that de state value is not updating the first time in the onChange event.

```
const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);

const handleCAmount = (event) => {    
  const value = Number(event.target.value);

  setAmount(value)  
};

<input
  className="card__data__amount"
  type="number" min="1" max="9" step="1" defaultValue="1"
      onChange={handleCAmount}
/>
```

Comment: One possible reason for this issue could be that the onChange event is triggered before the state is updated, leading to the initial value being used instead of the updated state value. To solve this, you can use the event.persist() method to remove the synthetic event from the pool, allowing references to the event to be retained asynchronously.

Comment: add, event.persist(); just after line const handleCAmount = (event) => {

Comment: How do you know that the state value is not updated? The given  code has no way of knowing it.

Comment: I see it in the console with console.log(amount)

Comment: The given code also has no `console.log`. The code that you provide should reproduce the problem you have, otherwise any answer can only be a guess.